# Disable mobile view of my angular application as i cant fit my application in mobile view

Tags: css, responsive-design

i am using angular for my web application as my web application is not mobile responsive, i want to disable it , when a user opens i need show a message like,
we doesn't support mobile view for this application

Comment: if you just want to show a message you can use css media query.

Comment: so i need to use media query for that particular screen width and how to show the message to user

Comment: Yes, You just need to change 1 css property i.e: `display: none;` to `display: block` in that media query.

Comment: Then how about message ??

Comment: Message will be in that Div you will use Media query on.

Comment: <div class="no-view">
    <p>We dont support mobile web browser</p>

  </div>

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .no-view {
    display: block;
  }

above is the code i have written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="no-view"> <p>We dont support mobile web browser</p> </div>
```

css:

```
.no-view  {
  display: none; // by default it is hidden
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .no-view {
    display: block;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: this dint work , still it is showing me the login page

Comment: what you mean by Login Page?

Comment: i need disable users login in mobile web browser as my application is not responsive.

Comment: you can make it position absolute with backdrop in mobile view on all views.

Comment: sorry i dint understand as of now i have written this,@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .login-card {
    display: none;
  }

Comment: can you make stackblitz..

Comment: yea sure i can come send your username

Comment: just make stackblitz and post link here.

Comment: Issue solved , thank you

Comment: stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lgzkxa